# ubuntu boot stick black screens, what should i do?

Tags: nvidia, live-usb

Hello i got the problem that the Ubuntu live Stick black screen after starting.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't download and install the Nvidia driver package on the machine with the Nvidia graphics adapter? That would be far simpler than what you're describing. If the target machine has no (cheap) internet connection, you can always download the installation package elsewhere with a different machine and store the package on the drive with the Live Ubuntu system for later installation.

Comment: @DavidFoerster the problem is if i boot the ubuntu live stick on the pc with an nvidia graphics card i get no signal. In my Oppinion the missing Drivers are responsible for that, so i wantedt to preinstall them

Comment: Ah, but you can likely work around that with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter. See [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](/q/162075/175814) for this and other possible solutions/workarounds. Could you please try that and report back with the result?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks a lot for your answer. With the articel you linked i was able to find out that i was booting the Live USB in UEFI Mode, and because of that i wasn't able to start with *nomodeset*. Now i'll just use nomodeset, install the drivers and then install the whole system on my harddrive

Comment: Alright. I'm glad it worked out. In that case could you please [edit] your question to include the info from your first comment about the underlying issue, so I can conclusively vote to close your question as a duplicate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, your live USB stick just needs to have persistent storage enabled so you can save packages.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)